# How far along the crease can a non-striker stand?

Tags: rules, cricket

In cricket, how far along the crease is a non-striker allowed to stand to the right or left?

Could they stand at the boundary and still be in their ground, or is there a limit to the "width" of the crease?

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to stand outside the crease to the left or right, as the crease is of unlimited length; quoting from [Law 7.3 The popping crease](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/the-creases):

> The popping crease [...] shall be considered to be unlimited in length.

Other than taking a position which would obstruct the fielding side, there is no restriction in the Laws as to where the non-striker may stand.

Answer (score -2):

The non striker can stay and can start only in pitch zone, he can not start standing in infield or outfield.

Comment: Are you able to provide a quote from the Laws of Cricket to support this answer?